# Custom CdkStepper lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm new to angular.

I am building a custom stepper component extending the CdkStepper.

```
export class MyStepperComponent extends CdkStepper {
 // custom implementation
}
```

Then I am using the component with cdk-step inside

```
<my-stepper>
    <cdk-step>
        <component-one></component-one>
    </cdk-step>
    <cdk-step>
        <component-two></component-two>
    </cdk-step>
</my-stepper>
```

I need to implement lazy loading of the steps

I've read that people are using matTabContent or matStepContent directives and ng-template. But I don't want to use angular-material. So what I currently did works but it's not very nice:

```
<my-stepper #stepper>
    <cdk-step>
        <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selectedIndex === 0">
            <component-one></component-one>
        </ng-container>
    </cdk-step>
    <cdk-step>
        <ng-container *ngIf="stepper.selectedIndex === 1">
            <component-two></component-two>
        </ng-container>
    </cdk-step>
</my-stepper>
```

Is there a better way to do lazy loading with custom CdkStepper? How are matTabContent/matStepContent directives implemented? Should I write my own directive? If I should, then how?

Thanks in regard guys,
Mark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually matStepContent is just a simple directive that content a TemplateRef

what make a step loaded lazily is an another cdk module that called PortalModule

so the idea here is to create another step extend from CdkStep and rewrite your custom step to be lazy.

I create a repo for that to  show you an example [lazy step repo](https://github.com/souhail-chougrani/angular-cdk-stepper-lazy-step)

Comment: Thank you for such a nice answer and the example. That does the trick! I learned a lot. The best answer ever! Nice code!

PS.: Sorry for a late answer, wasn't checking StackOverflow for a long time.